# is it possible to create a custom http request method in nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, request

I am using npm request for calling external services from node js, its works but is it possible to create a custom request method in node and use it in npm request.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a method with `request`:

```
request({
    method: 'PUT',
    ...
```

Or use shortcuts like:

```
request.put(url)
```

etc.

See more at https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#convenience-methods